# Detection the age of fossils using the carbon dating method

Tags: radioactivity, half-life

The life of carbon-14 isotope is about 5 thousand years. But we still are able to detect traces of it in fossils which are older, more than 10 thousand years. Why?

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57679/why-is-carbon-dating-limit-only-40-000-years and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346525/what-is-the-most-recent-date-that-can-be-measured-using-carbon-14-dating

Comment: Fossils are not dated by carbon dating. K-Ar dating is likely to be more useful https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/dating-rocks-and-fossils-using-geologic-methods-107924044/#:~:text=removal%20from%20bioshpere-,K%2DAr%20dating,-1%2C000%20%2D%20billion%20of

Answer (score 9):

The half-life of $^{14}$C is $5730\pm40$ years. That means that after 5730 years, we would have 0.5 the original amount of it. After 11460 years we should have 0.25, and after 17190 years we should have 0.125, and after 22920 years we should have 0.0625. Since 6% of original should still be pretty observable, I am not sure what you are having problems with.

Nobody is saying that exactly after 5730 years, there will be no more $^{14}$C. Instead, we should have quite a lot left.

Comment: Another related fact: in radiometric dating, it's usually preferable (and accurate) to date objects whose age is presumably within *ten* half-lives of the target element. For instance, in this case it would be approximately 57300 years, and any older than that researchers usually look for other elements for radio dating.

Comment: I'm sure there is also a minimum. Too close to the initial, and we would have trouble figuring out if that is just some variation in the initial total amount. Do you happen to know what is the standard chosen for the minimum?

Comment: I personally haven't read about that, but a search on Google led me to https://www.nps.gov/subjects/geology/radiometric-age-dating.htm#:~:text=For%20young%20organic%20materials%2C%20the,between%20100%20and%2050%2C000%20years., which says that it's about 100 years. I don't know how it's estimated though.

Comment: Radiometric dating objects from the last century or so is a bit messy, for several reasons. The industrial revolution has dumped a lot of old carbon (which has virtually no C-14) into the atmosphere. OTOH, coal has non-trivial amounts of radioactive isotopes, including uranium. Also, nuclear testing in the mid 20th century messed up various other radioisotope profiles.

Comment: @PM2Ring the "messing up" caused by Nuclear testing actually means that radiocarbon dating still works (to some extent) right up to the present day. https://www.radiocarbon.com/ams-dating-forensics.htm and see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346525/what-is-the-most-recent-date-that-can-be-measured-using-carbon-14-dating

Comment: @ProfRob is it ok for me to be absolutely horrified by that?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Another isotope of interest is [chlorine-36](https://phys.org/news/2019-10-radioactive-chlorine-nuclear-antarctica.html), which has a half-life of ~300,000 years. It was produced in [bomb tests conducted above & under seawater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_explosion#List_of_underwater_nuclear_tests), although at the time the short-lived radioactive sodium was more of a concern due to its high activity.